# MCVS Compilation Error: missing ',' before '&'; fine on clang

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

The following code compiles perfectly fine under clang, and I can't figure out what's going on with MSVC that's causing it to fail with the following errors:

```
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    altertum\src\component\transform_manager.cpp    60
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ',' before '&'    altertum\src\component\transform_manager.cpp    60
Error   C2511   'void altertum::components::transform::TransformManager::gc(const int)': overloaded member function not found in 'altertum::components::transform::TransformManager'    altertum\src\component\transform_manager.cpp    61
Error   C2228   left of '.size' must have class/struct/union    altertum\src\component\transform_manager.cpp    63
```

The very strange thing is I don't know where it's getting this overloaded method from. The method is neither declared or defined in that manner.

Here's a minimal, complete, verifiable example for the issue:

```cpp
namespace altertum
{

struct Entity
{
    unsigned id;
};

class EntityManager
{
private:

public:
    EntityManager();
    ~EntityManager();

    Entity create();
    void destroy(Entity e);
    inline Entity make_entity(unsigned id, unsigned generation) const;

    bool alive(Entity e) const { return true; };
};

} // namespace altertum

namespace altertum
{
namespace components
{
namespace transform
{

struct TransformInstance { unsigned i; };
class TransformManager
{
private:
    /** Transform data. */
    struct TransformData {
        unsigned size;                      /** Number of used entries in arrays */
        unsigned capacity;                  /** Number of allocated entries in arrays */
        void * buffer;                      /** Raw buffer for data. */

        Entity * entity;                   /** The entity owning this instance. */
        float ** local;                    /** Local transform with respect to parent. */
        float ** world;                    /** World transform. */
        TransformInstance * parent;         /** The parent instance of this instance. */
        TransformInstance * first_child;    /** The first child of this instance. */
        TransformInstance * next_sibling;   /** The next sibling of this instance. */
        TransformInstance * prev_sibling;   /** The previous sibling of this instance. */
    };
    TransformData _data;

    inline TransformInstance make_instance(unsigned i) const { TransformInstance inst = { i }; return inst; }

public:    
    /** Create instance from Entity lookup */
    inline TransformInstance lookup(Entity e) const 
        { return make_instance(0); }
    /** run garbage collection for TransformManager */
    void gc(const EntityManager &em);

    void destroy(unsigned i) {}

}; // class TransformManager

}
}
} // namespace transform

using namespace altertum::components::transform;

/** run garbage collection for TransformManager */
void TransformManager::gc(const EntityManager &em) // <- line 60
{
    unsigned cache_misses = 0;
    while ( _data.size > 0 && cache_misses < 4 )
    {
        unsigned i = 0;
        if ( em.alive(_data.entity[i]) )
        {
            ++cache_misses;
            continue;
        }
        cache_misses = 0;
        destroy(i);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    /* code */
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

Am I accidentally using some C++11 feature that Visual Studio doesn't support? Compilation fails in both VS2015 Community and VS2013 Ultimate.

Comment: Can you reduce this down to a [mcve]?

Comment: Code looks fine at first glance, please post a [mcve].

Comment: Did you `#include "entity_manager.h"` in `"TransformManager.cpp"`?

Comment: @BaummitAugen, @NathanOliver; example posted. Fails in VS, compiles correctly in clang.

Comment: @JonathanHoward Does [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f5d3bfae3550292) compile with MSVC? Looks like a bug in the name lookup for me. Btw, if it should not compile, *that* would be an actual *minimal* example.

Comment: @BaummitAugen, yep, that compiles for me, the however replacing the explicit declaration of the namespace with the using statement causes it to fail. Thanks, guess I have a bug to report! And understood on the minimal example, didn't click that it would be a namespacing issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio apparently requires an explicit `using` statement for the root namespace when a `using` statement is declared for a subnamespace.

```
using namespace altertum;
using namespace altertum::components::transform;
```

I've submitted a Visual Studio bug for this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Just from looking at the error messages (since the code is not compilable), at the point that the `gc` function is defined, `EntityManager` is seen as a variable name, not a type.

Answer (score 0):

You have namespace issue. EntityManager is defined in the altertum namespace.

```
using namespace altertum::components::transform;

/** run garbage collection for TransformManager */
void TransformManager::gc(const altertum::EntityManager &em) // <- add altertum namespace
```

Comment: Hey @Cynan, gc() is defined within the altertum namespace, so that's not the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure of why Visual Studio 2010 treats the namespace different, but it compiles with that change. It also compiles if you add using namespace altertum.  VS is being extra picky about the namespaces.